# How do you disable the RSASSA-PSS cipher in Apache httpd servers linked to OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, apache

I have a Java v8 based client provided by an unresponsive vendor that still ships an old JDK where this bug is not yet fixed:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8226374

To work around the bug, I want to disable the RSASSA-PSS cipher. I am struggling to find what the RSASSA-PSS cipher is called in the world of OpenSSL.

What modification must I make to the following line to disable RSASSA-PSS?

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

Comment: RSASSA-PSS is not a ciphersuite, or cipher; it is a signature algorithm. It is only used in 1.3, and is controlled (only) by the sigalgs extensions -- which Apache can't configure. Do you need client auth aka client cert aka mutual auth for your application? If you can turn it off the client-side bug won't happen. Otherwise you must turn off _protocol_ 1.3 and limit yourself to 1.2 (or lower, but anything below 1.2 is now considered unsafe and often prohibited).

Comment: The server that refuses to cooperate has TLS1.3 disabled already (certs are required in this case), and it hasn't made a difference. Is RSASSA-PSS a properly of the certificate?

Comment: I came up with a decent answer after all, so see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, my original comment was wrong. I didn't realize that both OpenSSL and Java (JSSE) implement PSS signatures in TLS1.2 as an extension, so using 1.2 doesn't solve the problem by itself. (But 1.3 *requires* protocol signatures using RSA to be PSS, even when the cert signatures are allowed or required to be v1_5, so if either your server cert or the desired client cert is RSA you still can't use 1.3 for a client with broken PSS.)

However, on checking more thoroughly, apache *can* configure this at least in 2.4.8 up (assuming a suitable OpenSSL, which you obviously have). You need to use the [SSLOpenSSLConfCmd directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslopensslconfcmd) but apache's link to OpenSSL is stale, it is now https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html#SUPPORTED-CONFIGURATION-FILE-COMMANDS (but probably not much longer, 1.1.1 is going EOL soon). The following gives me a CertReq with no PSS schemes in 1.2 (and this time I tested instead of ass-u-ming):

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ClientSignatureAlgorithms ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1
```

For convenience I used the old (1.2) two-part naming because the 1.3 combined names are longer, and left out the SHA224 schemes (which I don't think anyone used), ed25519 and ed448 which a Java 8 client can't use, and the DSA schemes which are rare, but if your client(s) use them add them back.

To your additional Q: Is RSASSA-PSS a properly of the certificate? Yes, but not the way you want :-(
A certificate for an RSA key can have a PSS-specific value for the identifying OID which *requires* use of PSS for that key -- but I don't know of any CA that issues certs with this new OID. OTOH a cert with the older generic OID (which is still pretty much universal) *permits* use of PSS; in 1.3 nomenclature these are the rsa_pss_rsae schemes versus the rsa_pss_pss schemes. In any case the bug you linked appears to occur in the setup for selecting a client cert, and processing could not be affected by the content of a cert that hasn't been selected yet. (To be clear, if you meant the *server* cert nothing in the server cert ever affects *client* signatures, neither in 1.2 or 1.3.)

Comment: Got a chance to confirm the workaround, and we have success - the JDK with the problem now connects when it crashed in the past. Thank you hugely for the detailed explanation.